# Firebase modifying uid in every view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to make a sign-up form using multiple views. The problem is that after calling **Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid** 
I get a different String in each view, being unable to continue doing work on one specific UID. What am I doing wrong?

I'm creating the user using the firebase function createUser as so:

```
 Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: 
 passField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let user = user {
                let userInfo: [String : Any] = ["uid": UserModel().getUID(),
                                                "username": self.usernameField.text!, "avatar_icon" : ""]
                self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(userInfo)
            }
        })
```

I've tried creating a model class that holds that specific string, but getting the same bad results.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class UserModel {
    var userID : String

    init() {
       self.userID = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
  }

    func getUID() -> String {
       return self.userID
  }

}
```

My first sign-up view controller is Register1ViewController, where I call             **UserModel.init()**, getting the uid with **UserModel().getUID()** in the future view controllers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update your question to include the code for your sign-up views. Include the minimal, complete amount of code required to reproduce the issue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link to find out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At firebase every authenticated user have only one "unique" uID as you know. So when you logged in as a user, you should allways get the same uID when you query it. It is hard to say this from here because you provided little part of this code. You should provide more to get an answer.

EDIT:
It looks like you are calling createuser everytime your activity starts. That means you are creating another user every time you run the code. And the

> Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

returns you different uID. You should register once and log-in other times. You can check tutorial below. But dont just look snippets, open github code.

https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-login-signup/

Comment: My whole code is irrelevant to this issue, calling in every view just the common: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid returns a different string. I've edited my post and added the createUser function, as I have used. Thank you for your suggestion :)